# How to change imageView of an xml from another activity?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout

KOTLIN 
I want to change my Image in navHeader.xml file from an another activity.
It want be done via:

```
val getImage = registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
            ActivityResultCallback {
                binding.sampleImage.setImageURI(it)
            }
        )

        binding.sampleImage.setOnClickListener{
            getImage.launch("image/*")
        }
// where sample image is the image Id
// but the problem with this method is that, it is working only for imageViews which are
// inside the current Activity
```

But I want to change my image of an navHeader.xml which has not class using my current activity.

Current Activity:

```
package com.example.driftdb

import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.widget.*
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.example.driftdb.databinding.ActivityAccountSettingsBinding
import com.example.driftdb.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference


class AccountSettings : AppCompatActivity(){
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityAccountSettingsBinding
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var sharedPref: SharedPreferences
    private lateinit var userPhoneNumber: String
    private lateinit var userName: String
    private lateinit var imgView: ImageView

    private val getImage = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
        ActivityResultCallback {
            imgView = findViewById(R.id.circularImageView)
            imgView.setImageURI(it)
        }
    )

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityAccountSettingsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        supportActionBar?.hide()

        binding.avatar.setOnClickListener{
            avatarSettings(getImage)
        }
    }

    private fun avatarSettings(getImage: ActivityResultLauncher<String>) {
        getImage.launch("image/*")
        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "AVATAR",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

NavHeader.xml file which does not have any class :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/userProfileImage"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24"
        android:background="@drawable/user_profile_avatar"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/navheader_userName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Name Not Set"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/navheader_userPhoneNumber"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@color/underline"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

userProfileImage is the image that I want to change.
Any working solution ?

Comment: Sorry I missed that part, now I have added the working in the oncreate() function.
Now can you look into it

Comment: In the getImage value, there is " imgView = findViewById(R.id.circularImageView) "
On run, it says ImageView can not be null

Comment: yes, I want to change userProfileImage which is a ImageView in navHeader.xml file which has no class associated to it. Now, I asking if there is a way to use this ImageView in another activity and then change it's Image from your phone-gallery

Comment: Technically, yes. You want to change `android:id="@+id/userProfileImage"` but you are trying to find `R.id.circularImageView`?